# Android - How to see only friends' posts on firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a semi social media app that has friends. On the friends page, I want the user to see posts only made by their friends.

I am using  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and query.

The friend data is saved like this:

```
Friends:
        userA:
              userB: true
              userC: true
```

How do I set the query so that userA is able to userB and Cs posts?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to query your database twice. First of all you need to query `Friends -> userA` to see which friends have the value set to `true`  and then get them. Based on `userB`, `userC` you need to query again, to find actually the posts corecponding to this users. Assuming that your database looks like this `Friends -> userB -> Posts>` and `Friends -> userC -> Posts>`, you need to query only this posts.

Hope it helps.